# Change UITableView contentInset iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView in my view controller which is root of a UINavigationController, and i have a text UITextField inside some cells. When the user taps some cell or start editing a text field, i want to scroll my table to that cell.

In iOS 6 i used to change table's contentInset and then use scrollToRowAtIndexPath method to scroll to selected cell.

Something like this:

```
self.tableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 200, 0);

[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

Now in iOS 7 this approach doesn't seens to work. My view controller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is set to YES and my table is positioned just fine until i change it's `contentInset` (bottom parameter), it goes to the top of the view, doesn't matter what value i put on bottom parameter, the table just goes on top.

My table is the first sub view in the main view.

How can i make the iOS 6 code works? Or there's another approach to accomplish what i want?

Comment: Is your navigation bar translucent ? I ask that because you set automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets to YES.

Comment: It's not translucent, automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is setted to YES as default.

Comment: if the result of `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(_tableView.contentInset))` is {64, 0, 0, 0}. You should set `self.tableView.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 200, 0);` instead.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i've been busy lately. KudoCC's solutions worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an Easy solution to it.

[TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

It is available for UITableView with UITextField , UICollectionView with UITextField and UIScrollView with UITextField